# Animación con PictureBox en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, animación, picturebox

Tengo este codigo que lo que hace es incrementar el tamaño de un pictureBox pero la animacion no es del todo fluida, me gustaria saber si alguien conoce alguna manera de hacerlo fluido.

Estoy modificando la publicacion porque la primera vez no añadi esto donde el codigo usa un timer, posteriormente el timer es el que tiene el codigo donde se realiza la animacion.

```
 public void container(String anworte, int round)
        {
            round--;
            if (round == 1)
            {
                switch (anworte)
                {
                    case "C03":
                        imgC03.BackgroundImage = Prototype9.Properties.Resources.cbpot;
                        img = imgC03;
                        for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++)
                        {
                            timer1.Start();
                        }
                        break;
```

Gracias a la respuesta de David Cárcamo, he modificado estas lineas de codigo sustituyendolas por estas pero la animacion sigue sin ser fluida.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                img.Size = new Size(img.Width + 2, img.Height + 1);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            if (img.Width == 342)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
```

Respecto a la pregunta de gbianchi uso Windows Forms

Comment: winforms o wpf??? tene en cuenta que en winforms las animaciones no son fluidas...

Comment: Windows Forms, no conocia la existencia de WPF, por lo poco que he leido es mas actual y tiene mejores implementaciones?

Comment: si, es mucho mas actual y permite una interaccion mas fluida con la UI. Lo que vos queres hacer con threads sale fluido y solo en wpf...

Comment: igual ojo, por mas actual, hablamos de 10 años o mas...

Comment: Podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]?... de paso, si una respuesta te sirvio, aunque no haya contestado tu pregunta, considera darle un voto positivo.

Comment: Le he dado positivo pero tengo menos de 15 de "reputacion" o no se como le ha llamado y no se muestra publicamente. Por otro lado me refiero a actual comparando ambos, uno salio en 2002 y el otro en 2006. Gracias, me mirare el recorrido y el como preguntar

Comment: No te preocupes. Pero en las pregutnas que haces vos, no importa tu reputacion, podes hacer todo, y todo lo que pasa aca es publico.bah, salvo quien vota positiva o negativamente...

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la bienvenida. Ahora dime que recomiendas, migrar todo el proyecto a WPF porque es imposible hacerlo en Windows Forms?

Comment: No es imposible, pero como viste, se creo wpf, y ahora en el futuro corto se va a migrar a MAUI que es mas similar a wpf que a winforms. winforms, esta casi obsoleto. Se puede en winforms. solo que es mucho mas complicado. Lo que si, yo no recuerdo como, hace mucho que nada de winforms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final mi codigo ha quedado de esta forma y no solo modifica el tamaño si no que tambien la posicion del mismo para que este pueda empezar desde el centro de un recuadro.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while(img.Width < 342)
            {
                img.Size = new Size(img.Width + 8, img.Height + 4);
                img.Refresh();
                img.Location = new Point(img.Location.X - 4, img.Location.Y - 2); 
            }
                timer1.Stop();        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás incrementando el tamaño demasiado de golpe y por eso te va a golpes.

Poner esa instrucción 10 veces seguidas es lo mismo que poner:

```
img.Size = new Size(img.Width + 20, img.Height + 10);
```

Prueba a espaciar las instrucciones con un sleep.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    img.Size = new Size(img.Width + 2, img.Height + 1);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: Esto no va a aumentar de a poco, porque como es un solo thread, no va a aumentar el tamaño hasta tanto no termine la funcion...

Comment: Me di cuenta de ello, por eso uso el timer, provoca que se incremente de forma progresiva pero se ve demasiado "robotico"